# What is the correct way to go from LocalDate to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a `LocalDate` that I'm trying to convert to a `java.sql.Date` to store it in a Date field in the DB. My problem is that when I convert it to a `java.sql.Date` it is one day behind due to the machine I'm running on being in EST. I setup `Joda.DateTime` to be in UTC, and creating the `java.sql.Date` via using the millis constructor. I'm including the output of the debug watches so you can see what the different values are:

```
item.getDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() = {org.joda.time.DateTime@6079}"2013-09-25T00:00:00.000Z"
item.getDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis() = 1380067200000
new java.sql.Date(item.getDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()) = {java.sql.Date@6082}"2013-09-24"
item.getDate().getLocalMillis() = 1380067200000
new java.sql.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()) = {java.sql.Date@6083}"2013-09-24"
new java.util.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()) = {java.util.Date@6103}"Tue Sep 24 20:00:00 EDT 2013"
```

From the `java.util.Date` creation I'm assuming it is because my machine I'm testing on is in EST, and the LocalDate is in UTC, but I'm not sure what the correct way to fix this is. I realize I could get the local timezone and add that to the millis, but that seems like a hacky fix. Is there a proper way to do this that I'm just missing?

---

Update with the millis for the `java.util.Date`

```
new java.util.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()).getTime() = 1380153600000
item.getDate().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis() = 1380153600000
item.getDate() = {org.joda.time.LocalDate@5812}"2013-09-26"
new java.sql.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()).getTime() = 1380153600000
new java.util.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()) = {java.util.Date@5842}"Wed Sep 25 20:00:00 EDT 2013"
new java.util.Date(item.getDate().getLocalMillis()).getTime() = 1380153600000
```

Comment: What's the millisecond value of the sql and util `Date` objects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper conversions are:

```
    public static final DateTimeZone jodaTzUTC = DateTimeZone.forID("UTC");

    // from  java.sql.Date  to LocalDate:
    public static LocalDate dateToLocalDate(java.sql.Date d) {
        if(d==null) return null;
        return new LocalDate(d.getTime(), jodaTzUTC);
    }

    // from  LocalDate to java.sql.Date:
    public static java.sql.Date localdateToDate(LocalDate ld) {
        if(ld==null) return null;
        return new java.sql.Date(
             ld.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(jodaTzUTC).getMillis());
    }
```

I use this in my DAO helper logic. In JDBC you should do

```
 public static final Calendar calendarUTC = Calendar.getInstance(
       TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

 d = rs.getDate(i, calendarUTC);
```

And the same for the setter.

Answer (score 4):

Let's you have joda's local date

```
LocalDate loc = //...
```

You can conver it to `java.sql.Date` with independence of zone, in next ways:

```
Date date = new Date(loc .getYear() - 1900, loc .getMonthOfYear() - 1, loc .getDayOfMonth());
```

or

```
Date date = Date.valueOf(l.toString());
```

Comment: This constructor is deprecated

Answer (score -2):

You should create and use a java.sql.Timestamp, not a java.sql.Date.
By spec, the java.sql.Date has no time element.

To convert LocalDate to Timestamp:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(localDate.toDateMidnight().getMillis());
```

To convert LocalDateTime to Timestamp:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(localDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis());
```

Comment: I don't need a timestamp I need a date, I'm storing a date in the database.

Comment: LocalDate has no time element as well, just like java.sql.Date

Answer (score -3):

If you found this question by searching how to convert **Java 8** LocalDate, here is how you do it:

> public static Date valueOf(LocalDate date)
>
> Obtains an instance of Date from a LocalDate object with the same
>   year, month and day of month value as the given LocalDate.  The
>   provided LocalDate is interpreted as the local date in the local time
>   zone. Parameters:date - a LocalDate to convertReturns:a Date
>   objectThrows:NullPointerException - if date is nullSince:1.8

example:

```
Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(localDateObject);
```

Comment: This confuses Joda LocalDate with Java 8 LocalDate. The question is about Joda LocalDate.